# Gufw doesn't show my current iptables rules

Tags: iptables, gufw

I bought a new machine, so, what I did was save my current iptables using `iptables-save` and imported the rules into the new machine with `iptables-restore` command.

If I run `iptables -L` command in the new machine I can see all my rules, but if I open Gufw I can't see them.

Somebody can help me?
nonox

Answer (score 2):

Gufw is a front-end for *ufw*, which in turn is a simple interface/front-end to iptables.

Gufw does not display your existing iptables rules because it is only designed to interpret the high-level ufw rules; it simply cannot parse the low-level iptables rules.

Comment: Thanks!
You right, what I did was save my current ufw rules (/lib/ufw/user.rules) and copy them in my new machine and everything works fine!